# Cant insert unix date properly using $date in MongoDB (4.2)

Tags: mongodb

im running this simple insert with unix timestamp:

```
db.tasks.insert([{
        "createdAt": {
        "$date": 1623012341101
    }
}])
```

and it get inserted with

```
Invalid Date
```

it looks like this:

[image]

why is that?

Comment: Try `"createdAt": new Date(1623012341101)`

Comment: Construct a Date using the `new Date()` or `ISODate()` constructor in the mongo shell, see [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the thing is that I get a json from api call that return me this $date and im inserting it to my db

Comment: Are you getting that JSON in the mongo shell, or something else?